# Adding a method to a Class protoype, error

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Quick question about adding a method to an object.

Why do I get errors back?
I checked the syntax and it seem correct.
New to Javascript.

```
// create your Animal class here
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}

// create the sayName method for Animal
Animal.prototype.sayname = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};

// test
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

I get this error back when trying to run the code

```
TypeError: Object #<Animal> has no method 'sayName'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, because you've declared the method as `sayname` with small `n` letter.

JavaScript is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 1):

You called `sayName()` and the function added is `function sayname(){}`.